# Javascript sorting out nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have script that is for a Bingo game.  I'm having a problem running one of my functions inside another function.  The idea was to have my checkBingo() function be defined outside of a .click() function.  There's some ajax at work, so I'm not sure if that's coming into play here too.  Looks something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function checkBingo() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/check-bingo',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
        return data;
      } 
    }):
  }

  $('#div').click(function() {
    // Some stuff gets done here
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tile',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
    // Does some stuff with data, then needs to check if there's a bingo.
        var isBingo = checkBingo();

        if (isBingo == 'something') {
          // Displays something specific on the page.
        }  else {
          // Displays other things on the page.
        }
  }
  }):
});
```

Where I'm getting hung up, is that isBingo is never getting assigned the returned info.  I thought it might have been because the query wasn't running fast enough, so I've tried sticking the variable in a loop until it got something assigned to it and then the console told me that my checkBingo() inside the .click function wasn't defined.  I'm not sure if it's just a stupid syntax error on my part or if what I'm doing isn't possible.

Can someone verify that this is indeed possible and that I've probably just got to scour it for the syntax error?

Comment: run check-bingo on its own in the browser by just using its url and see what you get back.

Comment: Why are there colons `:` where there should be semicolons?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Where?

Comment: Is this line right? `('#div').click(function() {` - looks like it's missing a `$` at the beginning. That plus the other syntax errors. Do you have a syntax-checking editor? If you load your code into [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) it will show you your errors with squiggly red underlines.

Comment: You're missing a `$` before `('#div')`. Also, AJAX is asynchronous (that's what the **A** stands for), so `return data` won't do anything useful.

Comment: And if you don't want to try Komodo (but you really should), simply opening the Developer Tools in Chrome or other browsers would show you the errors in the JavaScript console.

Comment: @MichaelGeary that was a typo in my psuedo code.  I tried to post the gist of everything without exposing too much of the irrelevant stuff.  My actual code was passing all of the syntax checking, but I had a feeling that I was misusing ajax.

I am indeed using an IDE with syntax checking, but I will definitely check out Komodo.

Comment: Weird.  Chrome shows colons instead of semicolons for each function.  Maybe it's a Chrome or SO issue if your code actually has semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this line:

```
var isBingo = checkBingo();
```

...is calling an function (`checkBingo`) which makes an asynchronous call and does not return anything, `isBingo` will be undefined.

One way to approach this would be to pass a callback function to `checkBingo` since JavaScript allows functions to be passed around like data, and the function will be called by jQuery when the data is obtained from the server:

```
function checkBingo(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/check-bingo',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
      callback(data);
    }
    // or you could just do:
    // success: callback,
  });
}

// ....

success: function(data){
    checkBingo(function (isBingo) {
        if (isBingo == 'something') {
          // Displays something specific on the page.
        }  else {
          // Displays other things on the page.
        }
    });
```

Another approach, which *would* allow you to continue using your synchronous style (i.e., where `checkBingo` could return something and you could immediately use it) even though the code is not executed synchronously is by taking advantage of the fact that the later versions of jQuery's Ajax API return a promise object which allows this style of coding:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function checkBingo() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/check-bingo.txt',
            type: 'GET'
        });
    }

    $('#div').click(function() {
        // Some stuff gets done here
        $.ajax({
            url: '/tile.txt',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
                var checkingBingo = checkBingo();
                checkingBingo.done(function (isBingo) {
                    if (isBingo == 'something') {
                        alert('a');
                        // Displays something specific on the page.
                    }  else {
                        alert('b');
                        // Displays other things on the page.
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Besides the need to convert a couple of your colons into semi-colons, and add the jQuery `$` in front of your "#div" code, two other aspects to note:

1. I added the ".txt" extension to the Ajax calls in case the extension was merely hidden on your system.
2. The code `$('#div')` presumes that there is an element on your page with the ID set to "div". If you want all `div` elements to be clickable, you would simply need to do `$('div')`.

Comment: Why is there a `return` before `callback(data)`?

Comment: Because I'm not thinking. :)  Of course, there's no harm, but I removed it.

Comment: You already had my up-vote, Async can be weird for people just learning JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, but it is pretty important to start learning. I added jQuery's promise API for the second call (as I could have done also for the first one) in case it is easier.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used your second suggestion and it's working like a charm.  And just fyi my urls were '/check-bingo' because it's on Google's app engine and I've got a handler set up to respond to that url.